# Restart windows app when it uses more RAM than needed

Tags: c#, powershell

I need to make kind of script or program which restarts the required windows application when it uses more RAM than 1GB for example. I want to use powershell, but got stuck on getting RAM usage of given app into a variable. I tried `$OutputVariable = (Get-Process %processname% | Select-Object WS) | Out-String`  but that doesn't work, cause I need the value only.

Comment: Are you sure you really want to do this!? It would be better to fix the application to remove the memory leak or remove in memory objects.

Comment: That's third-party app, unfortunately I can't fix that, thanks for advice anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
(Get-Process explorer).WS
```

will give you the value only. But I guess you'd better fix that memory leak instead.

see

[What are ways to solve Memory Leaks in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690071/what-are-ways-to-solve-memory-leaks-in-c-sharp)

[What strategies and tools are useful for finding memory leaks in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134086/what-strategies-and-tools-are-useful-for-finding-memory-leaks-in-net)

[How to use IDisposable to fix memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112011/how-to-use-idisposable-to-fix-memory-leaks)

among others

Comment: You could do `$OutputVariable = ((Get-Process %processname%).ws/1048576)` to get you from KB to GB.

Comment: `(Get-Process %processname%).WS` / 1MB :-)

Comment: It *seems* this is available even in PS2 according to a few searches

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I was recycling code and setting a variable instead of running the process.  Ah, details.  :)